# Эффект чего или от чего

Tags: грамматика

Когда используется "эффект чего-то", а когда "эффект от чего-то"? Буду благодарна за ссылки на правило, если оно есть.

Answer (score 3):

Разница **в грамматике**:

**Эффект (чего? какой?)** — определение, беспредложное управление,  Р. п.

**Эффект (от чего?)** — дополнение, предлог ***ОТ***, Р. п.

**Примеры:**

1. **Эффект (чего? какой?)**

**Эффект сжатия времени** определяется как уверенность в том, что время идет быстрее, чем мы воспринимаем. Ученые считают, что этот эффект может существовать, потому что мы не так осведомлены о своем физическом теле, находясь в мире виртуальной реальности - среде, где вы не видите ничего там, где обычно находится ваше тело.

**Эффекты восприятия** – это то, что движет нашими эмоциями при знакомстве с окружением

С помощью какой программы добивается **эффект искажения** видеоряда и звука, которым часто пользуются в американских мемах?

2. **Эффект (от чего?)**

Позитивный **эффект от ухода** персонажа состоит в том, что зритель испытывает сострадание.  Андрей Геласимов. Рахиль // «Октябрь», 2003

Выверяя **эффект от сказанного**, глянул на гостя.  Семен Данилюк. Бизнес-класс (2003)

**[Нацкорпус](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CnEiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHgocChoKA3JlcRITChHRjdGE0YTQtdC60YIg0L7RgjAA)**